# Basic timer that doesn't work STM32L4

Tags: stm32, timer, stm32cubemx

I'm trying to use timer2 in STM32L475 but it doesn't start firing the interrupt at all.

I would like to configure the timer for a minute.

```
void InitializeTimer()
{
    TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef sSlaveConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 10000;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 500;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
          _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sSlaveConfig.SlaveMode = TIM_SLAVEMODE_RESET;
  sSlaveConfig.InputTrigger = TIM_TS_ITR0;
  if (HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sSlaveConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
          _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
          _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }


if(HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
{
  _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}

}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if (htim->Instance == TIM2) {
          start_processing = true;

    }
}

void TIM2_IRQHandler()
{
    /* Clear interrupt flag first. It cannot be the last instruction in an interrupt handler. */
     __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_FLAG(&htim2, TIM_FLAG_UPDATE);            //clear interrupt flag
    start_processing = true;
}
```

before main loop:

```
 MX_I2C3_Init();
  InitializeTimer();
  //MX_SPI3_Init();
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, 0, 1);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);// Enable interrupt from TIM3 (NVIC level)
```

Comment: Some things to check: Does it start counting and reach the limit? What is the master timer (`TIM1`?) doing?  Does it work without the master-slave configuration? Is `start_processing` declared as `volatile`? What do the control and status registers contain?

Comment: @berendi yes start_processing declared as volatile. Can you show a basic setup without master and slave ?

Comment: @berendi HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback is never called

Comment: The period value seems to be way too low for one minute. Does the controller run in some reduced frequency (low power) mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback()` is never called because there is no code to call it. It is supposed to be called from `TIM2_IRQHandler()`.

Here is a basic timer setup with interrupts every minute, assuming the APB1 clock is 80 MHz.

```
volatile int start_processing;
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void) {
    if(TIM2->SR & TIM_SR_UIF) {    // check status
        start_processing = 1;
        TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;   // clear status
    }
}

void InitializeTimer(void) {
    RCC->APB1ENR1 |= RCC_APB1ENR1_TIM2EN;
    RCC->APB1ENR1;
    TIM2->PSC = 9999;           // 80 MHz clock is prescaled to 8 kHz
    TIM2->EGR = TIM_EGR_UG;     // required to take over the ARR value
    TIM2->ARR = 479999;         // 8000 * 60 - 1
    TIM2->DIER = TIM_DIER_UIE;  // enable update (timer overflow) interrupt
    TIM2->CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN;    // start timer
    NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, 0);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
}
```